# Sort With Buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make it so when you click one of the buttons all other words disappear except the word starting with that letter. I am very new to javascript and do not know how to do this.

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="A">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="B">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="C">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="D">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="E">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="F">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="G">
</div>

<div>
<p>aas</p>
<p>bas</p>
<p>cas</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>eas</p>
<p>fas</p>
<p>gas</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `getElementsByTagName("P")` to set `hidden` attribute of `<p>` elements appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches to solve your problem. One could be:

1. Get a list of all element in your div. To do so you should give your div an id, and then get the elements in it with "document.getElementById("yourDIVid").childNodes".
2. Loop through those elements. For each element look if its text attribute starts with the letter you clicked on.
3. 1. In order to accomplish this you first need to get the button you clicked on. You can attach event-listeners to elements: One of them being the onclick-event. You should execute some function that shows all elements starting with the letter of your button.
4. 2. Check if the first letter of the element is the one of the button. If yes, make it visible. Else, make it invisible. (element.style.display = "none"|"block")
5. Thats it!
6. Here some pseudo-code:

   ```
   <script>
   function showElementsStartingWith(containerId, letter){
       document.getElementById(containerId).childNodes.forEach(function(value){
           value.style.display = value.text.startsWith(letter)?"block":"none";
       });
   }
   </script>

   <!-- Modify your buttons -->
   <input type="button" class="btn" value="A"     onclick="showElementsStartingWith('myDIV', 'A')">
   ```

This is a primitive, but working, example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```js
$('.btn').click(function(a) {
  var filt = this.value.toLowerCase();
  $('div p').hide();
  $("div p").each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var text = that.text();
    if (text.startsWith(filt))
      that.show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="A">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="B">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="C">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="D">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="E">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="F">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="G">
</div>

<div>
  <p>aas</p>
  <p>bas</p>
  <p>bass</p>
  <p>cas</p>
  <p>cass</p>
  <p>das</p>
  <p>eas</p>
  <p>fas</p>
  <p>gas</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript only solution.

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].onclick = function() {
    var letter = this.value[0];
    var paras = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    for (var j = 0; j < paras.length; j++) {
      if (paras[j].innerHTML.toUpperCase()[0] != letter.toUpperCase()) {
        paras[j].style.display = "none";
      } else {
        paras[j].style.display = "inherit";
      }
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="A">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="B">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="C">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="D">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="E">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="F">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="G">
</div>

<div>
  <p>aas</p>
  <p>bas</p>
  <p>cas</p>
  <p>das</p>
  <p>eas</p>
  <p>fas</p>
  <p>gas</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you putting the favascript at the bottom of the page? What error are you getting

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="A" onclick="searchval(this)">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="B" onclick="searchval(this)">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="C" onclick="searchval(this)">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="D" onclick="searchval(this)">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="E" onclick="searchval(this)">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="F" onclick="searchval(this)">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="G" onclick="searchval(this)">
</div>

<div id="words">
<p>aas</p>
<p>bas</p>
<p>cas</p>
<p>das</p>
<p>eas</p>
<p>fas</p>
<p>gas</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function searchval(n)
{
    var s = n.value;
    var wordsele = document.getElementById("words");
    var words = wordsele.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var re = new RegExp("^" + s, "i");
    for (var i = 0, ele; ele = words[i]; i++)
    {
        var myword = ele.innerHTML;
        words[i].style.display = (!myword.match(re)) ? "none" : "block";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** *Updated so the paragraphs collapse down instead of staying in their original places.*

Here's a working javascript solution. Give `onclick` event listeners to each button. When clicked execute the `clicked( element )` function. This function hides all elements in your div, giving them the `noDisplay` class which has the `display:none` rule. Then we check if the first letter of the paragraph matches with the value of the button. If a match is found, that paragraph is made visible. Hope this helps!

```js
function clicked( element ){
  var everyChild = document.querySelectorAll( '#wrapper p' );
  for( var i = 0; i < everyChild.length; i++ ){
    everyChild[ i ].classList.add( 'noDisplay' );
  } 
  
  for( var i = 0; i < everyChild.length; i++ ){
    if( element.value == everyChild[ i ].innerHTML.slice( 0, 1 ) ){
      everyChild[ i ].classList.remove( 'noDisplay' )
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input{
  text-transform:uppercase;
 }

.noDisplay{ display:none; }
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="a" onclick="clicked( this )">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="b" onclick="clicked( this )">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="c" onclick="clicked( this )">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="d" onclick="clicked( this )">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="e" onclick="clicked( this )">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="f" onclick="clicked( this )">
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="g" onclick="clicked( this )">
</div>

<div id="wrapper">
<p id ="aas">aas</p>
<p id="bas">bas</p>
<p id="cas">cas</p>
<p id="das">das</p>
<p id="eas">eas</p>
<p id="fas">fas</p>
<p id="gas">gas</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works but all the text stays in its original position instead of collapsing down.

Comment: @user3503074 
 
To get the text to collapse down use `display:none` in the CSS instead of `visibility:hidden`. I've updated it for you. Please click the green check next to my answer to accept it if it works for you so others can find this solution quickly, thanks.